# Epsilon-delta definition does not include monotonicity

Tags: calculus

I had a clarification regarding the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition
of continuity. This definition states that for all $\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$
such that
$$
0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon
$$
This seems like a necessary, but not sufficient condition to me. I
would modify this definition as: if $\epsilon_2>\epsilon_1>0,\exists\delta_2>\delta_1>0$ such that:
$$
0<|x-x_0|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon_1
$$
$$
0<|x-x_0|<\delta_2\implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon_2
$$

In other words, any sequence of $\epsilon,\delta$ that
satisfies the above definition should also exhibit that $\delta$
is an increasing function of $\epsilon.$ Where is my intuition wrong?

Comment: If you take the example of a constant map, that is continuous, you'll see that there is no reason to request *$\delta$ to decrease with $\epsilon$.*

Comment: One can prove that if the standard definition is satisfied, for any decreasing sequence of $\epsilon$ there is a decreasing sequence of $\delta$. So you are not really adding a new insight. It seems to me you regard continuity as defining $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$, which is a misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you give an example where the first definition fails? If not, I don't see how you can say it is insufficient.

Comment: @DavidK I'm interested in this proof, could you point me to it? Thanks

Comment: @MahdiRkioui If *some* $\delta$ gets the job done for a particular $\varepsilon$, then any $\delta' < \delta$ *also* gets the job done.  So, given $\varepsilon_n$, there is a $\delta_n$ which gets the job done.  For $\varepsilon_{n+1} < \varepsilon_n$, find a $\delta'$ which gets the job done, then choose $\delta_{n+1} = \min\{ \delta', \delta_{n}/2\}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Much simpler than I thought, thanks a lot.